# Removing Header on Python, Dataquest

Tags: python, header, slice

I'm learning how to code on Dataquest. I've hit a roadblock on Q5.

- Slice the weather list to remove the header.
- The slice should only remove the first element in the list.
- Assign the slice to new_weather.

How do I actually slice a list to remove the header?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What have to tried so far and how is it failing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to find out how to ask a question on this site.

Comment: I'm from Dataquest, you should reach out to our support for help since we have the context.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is remove the first element of the list then it is very simple:

```
a = ['header','body','tail']
del a[0]
```

OR

```
a = ['header','body','tail']
a.pop(0)
<<< 'header'
```